# Magento flat catalog product - 1, 2 and 3

Tags: magento

When using the flat catalog option in magento, why does magento have the following tables:

```
flat_catalog_product_1
flat_catalog_product_2
flat_catalog_product_3
```

Why not just 1 single table?

Comment: It will create more tables if you have more products

Comment: @magalter actually, not. see the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each table corresponds to a Store View in Magento.

Because you can define an attribute like the product name or description to be at a store view level, the "flat" version of this information needs to be in a different table for each store view.

More about this: [Flat tables in Magento and product collection](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/flat-tables-in-magento-and-product-collection/)